# Android FragmentActivity not returning to previous

Tags: android, stack, android-fragmentactivity

I have 3 fragment activities: home screen, a news feed, and an article view. Clicking the button on the home screen opens the news feed, clicking an article in the news feed opens the article view. But when I click the "Back" button in the article view, it returns to the home screen.

Is there any reason it would be skipping the previous activity? How do I make sure it goes back to the calling activity rather than the home screen?

Comment: Are you using fragmentactivity or fragments? 
If fragmentActivity then check if you are calling finish() in your newsfeed activity?

Comment: FragmentActivities. The feed is part of a FragmentActivity that allows swiping between the feed and a webview, the article is a fragment in another FragmentActivity that swipes between articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` to the activities that opened the article.

I think the issue was that the activity was getting destroyed when I switched to the article activity and when it tried to go back there was nothing there.